# Replace first character in a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, select, replace, substring

On my database MySQL I have this string :

```
19-003950
```

From this string I need extract only

```
003950
```

And transform to :

```
103950
```

replacing first character '0' to '1' in a string.

I have tried withous success this SQL query:

```
mysql> SELECT
    REPLACE (
        SUBSTRING_INDEX('19-003950', '-' ,- 1),
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX('19-003950', '-' ,- 1),
            1,
            1
        ),
        '1'
    ) AS NEWSTRING;
+-----------+
| NEWSTRING |
+-----------+
| 113951    |
+-----------+
1 row in set
```

Please can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
select 
    concat(
        '1',
        substring(str, locate('-', str) + 1)
    ) new_string
from (select '19-003950' str) t
```

`locate('-', str)` gives you the position of the dash in the string. You can add `2` to that and take everything from that position until the end of string. Finally, concatenate `'1'` at the beginning of the string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41a2fa45bc9bd1b716330095c3c3964f)**:

```
| new_string |
| :--------- |
| 103950     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select concat('1', right(reverse(substring_index(reverse('19-003950'),'-', 1)), 
             length(substring_index(reverse('19-003950'),'-', 1) - 1)))
```